# Moving a treeview from one tablelayoutpanel to another

Tags: c#, tablelayoutpanel

I am new to Visual C# 2010 Express and to programming at all. I found answers for a lot of questions I had here. But now I have a basic question and I can't find anything about this:

I have a form with a tablelayoutpanel with 2 rows and 3 columns. In the cell 1,1 is a treeview and in 1,2 another tableylayoutpanel. How can I move my treeview from one tlp to the other? I can't just click and drag it and I can't find anything in the properties. Is it possible to move controls from one tlp to another or do I have to create a new one, delete the old and rename the new?

To be clear: I don't want to do this with code. I just want to move the treeview in the designer.

Comment: "I can't just click and drag it"  Not sure what you are doing wrong.  I can drag the TreeView between the TLPs no problem.

Comment: Is it docked?  I find I have to undock controls before the designer will let me move from one cell to another.  Otherwise, I usually edit the designer.cs file directly...

Comment: Yes, that's it. It was docked. I thought it would just dock to the new TLP. Thanks.